# Registering my domain with a different service provider

Tags: domains, domain-registration, godaddy

Almost before one year I registered my domain with Godaddy for one year , and it expired 2 weeks ago, but it still seems Godaddy has the domain, and I can't register with another service provider.

How can register this domain from another service provider?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer the domain to another registrar after it has expired when it is in the 30 day Redemption Grace Period.  You can only renew it with the registrar is is registered with.

Comment: Actually you can as long as you transfer it. I just did it with my domain name from Godaddy after it had expired. It worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of hosts don't allow the transfer during the 30 day grace period (often called the registrar's grace period) as technically they now own the domain but "kindly" allow the registrant to renew, although they technically don't have to do this and some hosts don't!

GoDaddy do and also allow transfers during this period. See their FAQ here: http://help.godaddy.com/article/795

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue a request for Godaddy to release the domain to the new provider. Most domain registrators have an option to transfer a domain name. You will receive a confirmation code from Godaddy. You will also need another code which can be obtained from the Godaddy domain panel.